# Is it possible to stream an audio/video file from IOS to Android or Android to IOS via Web

Tags: android, ios, stream, webserver

One of our client wants to stream an audio/video file from it's device which can be either IOS or Android. Our main challenge is that we should be able to do it cross platform as well i.e. file can be streamed from IOS to IOS, IOS to Android, Android to Android and Android IOS. Is there any way it can be achieved whether directly or via using Web server. Only condition is that file should not be downloaded.

Comment: Dont know if direct streaming is possible, but using web server definately will work. How do you think youtube works;-)

Comment: Can you please share some links regarding this? It would be great help....